# What is a word for someone who is concerned with holding up their image?

Tags: single-word-requests

By this, I do not mean someone aware of how other people see them. I want to describe someone who is concerned with their personality being consistent. For example, someone who feels the need to always seem cool in front of his/her friends. Is there a word for this?

Answer (score 2):

First thought was ***[image-conscious.](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/image-conscious)***

> Adjective: concerned about the way one comes across to other people and the impression one creates.

Comment: (Mentioned in comments already I see ... Why don't people don't put answers up ?)

Answer (score 1):

from you description, i would go with insecure. as in someone who is insecure of themselves, will act for the crowd, whereas a secure person is confident in who they are, and not swayed by the crowd.

Comment: While this is likely true of many image/self-conscious people, there are a large group of insecure people who aren't image/self-conscious.

Comment: agreed, i'm not saying its definitive or encompassing. just the term i would use.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting question. I haven't come up with much, but maybe you could call such an individual *self-aware* or *self-conscious*. Such an individual is concerned with upholding, or living up to, their *self-conception*.

Comment: There is literally a term "*image conscious*".

Comment: @Dan Bron, I was thinking the poster wouldn't like 'image conscious' because it usually suggests being conscious of one's image *in the eyes of others*, which they explicitly say they are not interested in. Rather, the poster "want[s] to describe someone who is concerned with their personality being consistent." But the original post is a bit equivocal... [@]Isabelle, could you clarify a little?

Comment: I am so sorry. I was trying to use this word to describe a character from a book, and no matter what, he always tries to act cool, and tough. He acted this way, when it would definitely not benefit him, so I thought he could not possibly be image-conscious, because he would be aware of how his attitude was not helping his situation. But in fact, that still would make him image-conscious. Sorry if that makes absolutely no sense. Image conscious would fit. Sorry, Silenus, but I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

### Primper

- Somone who takes a curious amount of time to get ready; they will take the time to try and perfect every physical flaw with their image
  Verb[edit]
- Primp ‎(third-person singular simple present primps, present participle primping, simple past and past participle primped)
- To spend time improving one's appearance (often in front of a mirror)

Answer (score 0):

This person might be (or wants to be) a ***conformist***.

ODO:

> **[conformist](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/conformist)**
>   *NOUN*
>
> **1** A person who conforms to accepted behaviour or established practices
>
> ‘The final argument used by the public school is one of socialization
>   and their failed attempts to convince the masses that children need
>   indoctrination and must become social conformists by association with
>   their peers.’

Answer (score -3):

**congruent**

Adjusting your question: I want to describe someone who is concerned with their personality being congruent. Someone who feels compelled to always be congruent in front of his/her friends.

(Googled..) Definitions of congruent 
adjective
(1) in agreement or harmony.

> institutional and departmental objectives are largely congruent

(2) (of figures) identical in form; coinciding exactly when superimposed.

> Use just one cut - or draw a line - and divide this white shape into
>   two identical, congruent , parts.